# How to find the lower hierarchical level in a list of codes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of hierarchical codes:

```
11000000
11010000
11010100
11010200
11010300
11020000
11020200
11020300
...
```

where 11000000 is a cumulative sum of 1101.. 1102.. etc.

The lowest level doesn't necessarily end with 100, 200, 300 etc (though it doesn't go lower than that).

Sometimes it's:

```
42000000
42020000
50000000
```

So my question is: how do I automatically mark the lowest level within the hierarchy? I want to get rid of codes that point to cumulative sums.

---

I should've provided a better explanation, sorry.

The "higher" code is not the cumulative sum of other codes, it merely points to a value that is a cumulative sum.

```py
data = {
    11000000: 105,

    11010000: 50,
    11010100: 35,
    11010200: 15,

    11020000: 55,
    11020200: 50,
    11020300: 5,

    42000000: 150,
    42020000: 150,

    50000000: 200
}

df = pd.Series(data).to_frame().reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={"index": "code", 0: "Value"})

    code        Value
0   11000000    105
1   11010000    50
2   11010100    35
3   11010200    15
4   11020000    55
5   11020200    50
6   11020300    5
7   42000000    150
8   42020000    150
9   50000000    200
```

As you could see, `11000000`'s value is 100, which is a sum of `11010000` and `11020000` (each of them is also a cumulative sum - of `11010100`, `11010200` and `11020200`, `11020300`).

There's also `42000000` which only consists of one child code - `42020000`, so their values are equal.

Lastly, there might be codes like `50000000` that don't have children codes.

So to remove cumulative codes would get the following result:

```
    code        Value
2   11010100    35
3   11010200    15
5   11020200    50
6   11020300    5
8   42020000    150
9   50000000    200
```

Comment: I dont get the logic here. How do you see cumulatie sums here?

Comment: @Erfan I updated the initial post. I hope now it makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem resembles nested heading numbering where you only want to see the headings that have no further subheading.
This solution creates a group based on the first digit (=level) and recursively groups the subgroups based on the n-th digit.

When the list in a group has length 1, no more grouping is possible and we reached the last child along with the parent which we need to filter out.

```
from itertools import groupby

codes = [ 11000000, 11010000, 11010100, 11010200, 11010300, 11020000,
          11020200, 11020300, 42000000, 42020000, 50000000 ]

def lowest(codes, pos=0, lowcodes=[]):
    groups = [ list(lst) for _, lst in groupby(codes, key=lambda x: x[pos])]
    for lst in groups:
        # print(pos, lst)                  # uncomment to see what happens during recursion
        if len(lst) > 1:
            lowest(lst, pos+1)
        else:
            if lst[0][pos] != '0':         # filter out parent
                lowcodes.append(int(lst[0]))
            continue
    return lowcodes

strcodes= [str(code) for code in codes]     # use strings instead of ints
print(lowest(strcodes))
```

Prints:

```
[11010100, 11010200, 11010300, 11020200, 11020300, 42020000, 50000000]
```

**Linear solution**
This solution first removes all right padding zeros to form a list of strings ['11', '1101', '110101', '110102', ...]. It then checks whether these parts occurs at the beginning of the other elements in the list. If this is the case, it is a parent and the corresponding element in the original list can be removed.

```
codeparts = [ str(code).strip('0') for code in codes ]  # ['11', '1101',...]

for i, chk in enumerate(codeparts):
    if chk in [code[:len(chk)] for code in codeparts[i+1:]]:
        codes.remove(int(chk.ljust(8, '0')))

print(codes)
```

Comment: thanks so much for your efforts! I'll try your solution first thing in the morning